# How to place evenly spaced nodes in TikZ from (node1) to (node2)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I have a relatively long and shallow rectangle, on the bottom of which I need to place some nodes. I don't want to manually fit coordinates, and naturally, I don't want to copy the same code several times.

So far I have come up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,petri,arrows,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,>=stealth',very thick,color=black!50,
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black},show background rectangle,
    font=\sffamily,pics/two dots/.style={code={
     \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50}] 
     (#1-left) {};
    \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50},
    right=0pt of #1-left]
        (#1-right) {};
    \node [rectangle, fit=(#1-left) (#1-right)] (#1){};
    }},
    every pin edge/.style={<-,very thick},
    box/.style={draw,rectangle,inner sep=#1},box/.default=2mm]
  % 
  \node (W1)  {factorial:};
  \node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};

  %
  \node (g env) [box, fit=(W1) (fake1),
  pin={[text width=1cm,pin distance=10mm]left:global env}]
  { };
  %
  \path ([yshift=-20mm]W1.east)pic{two dots=w1fun}
    (w1fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (W1.east);
  %
  \node [below=of w1fun-left, align=left] {parameters: n \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (w1fun-left.center); 

  \path (w1fun-right.center) edge[->,to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}] 
    (node cs:name=g env,angle=183);
\foreach \angl/\idx in {185/6, 195/5, 345/4, 355/3, 357/2, 358/1}  
{  
  \draw (node cs:name=g env,angle=\angl) node [rectangle, draw] (fake2-\idx)  {};
  \node (E\idx-env) [below=5mm of fake2-\idx,box,
    pin={[pin distance=5mm]left:E\idx}] {n:\idx}
    edge [->] (fake2-\idx);

  \node (E\idx-code) [below=5mm of E\idx-env, align=center]{
       (* \idx \hskip5pt (factorial \pgfmathparse{int(\idx - 1)}\pgfmathresult))
    };
}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is not a "minimal" example, but the code in the \foreach is what is important.

What is happening here:

- The (g env) node is this wide shallow rectangle.
- I am using the \angle and \idx variables to 
  -- Find a displacement for the "anchor" nodes.
  -- Change the name of the "attached" nodes.
  -- Compute the value of the index in the example code

[image]

What I don't like here:

1. \pgfmathparse . I seem to be doing something wrong. I tried playing with the ($$) construction, but failed. Is there a better way to find the value of the index rather than using \pgfmathparse directly?
2. The angle. $$sin(x) != x$$, so I can't set a regular range for the loop. Is there some way to set the nodes equidistantly in an idiomatic way?

Comment: In order to make your code compilable you need to add the `backgrounds` library and move `\node (W1)  {factorial:};` before `\node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};` but then it still misses the node `make withdraw` which is part of the fit. Could you please make the code compilable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equidistant positioning is very easy to achieve with the `pos` syntax. In

```
foreach \idx  in {1,...,6}  
{  
   node [pos=\idx/7.5-1/7.5,rectangle, draw] (fake2-\idx)  {}
  node (E\idx-env) [below=5mm of fake2-\idx,box,
    pin={[pin distance=5mm]left:E\idx}] {n:\idx}
    edge [->] (fake2-\idx)
  node (E\idx-code) [below=5mm of E\idx-env, align=center]{
       (* \idx \hskip5pt (factorial \the\numexpr\idx-1))
    }
};
```

the position of the node is at `\idx/7.5-1/7.5`, and thus equidistant. For integers, you can use `\the\numexpr`, so you can get rid of the `\pgfmathparse`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,petri,arrows,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,>=stealth',very thick,color=black!50,
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black},show background rectangle,
    font=\sffamily,pics/two dots/.style={code={
     \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50}] 
     (#1-left) {};
    \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50},
    right=0pt of #1-left]
        (#1-right) {};
    \node [rectangle, fit=(#1-left) (#1-right)] (#1){};
    }},
    every pin edge/.style={<-,very thick},
    box/.style={draw,rectangle,inner sep=#1},box/.default=2mm]
  % 
  \node (W1)  {factorial:};
  \node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};
  %
  \node (g env) [box, fit=(W1) (fake1),
  pin={[text width=1cm,pin distance=10mm]left:global env}]
  { };
  %
  \path ([yshift=-20mm]W1.east)pic{two dots=w1fun}
    (w1fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (W1.east);
  %
  \node [below=of w1fun-left, align=left] {parameters: n \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (w1fun-left.center); 

  \path (w1fun-right.center) edge[->,to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}] 
    (node cs:name=g env,angle=183);
\path (g env.south east) -- (g env.south west) 
foreach \idx  in {1,...,6}  
{  
   node [pos=\idx/7.5-1/7.5,rectangle, draw] (fake2-\idx)  {}
  node (E\idx-env) [below=5mm of fake2-\idx,box,
    pin={[pin distance=5mm]left:E\idx}] {n:\idx}
    edge [->] (fake2-\idx)
  node (E\idx-code) [below=5mm of E\idx-env, align=center]{
       (* \idx \hskip5pt (factorial \the\numexpr\idx-1))
    }
}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I had to add the `backgrounds` library and move `\node (W1) {factorial:};` before `\node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};` and to drop the `make withdraw` from the fit to make the code compile. I also switched to the `standalone` class because the picture is a bit too wide for a regular article.

Comment: I didn't know that parameter values are evaluated before assignment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way how to write your image:

- first drawn nodes "factorial" in chain using loop
- than draw other nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                petri,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = Stealth,
 font = \small\sffamily,
 thick,
 color=gray!50,
 inner sep = 0pt,
 %
background rectangle/.style={fill=black}, show background rectangle,
 %
PN/.style = {place, minimum size=5mm, colored tokens={gray!50}},
pics/two dots/.style = {code={
    \node   [PN]                        (#1-left)   {};
    \node   [PN, right=0pt of #1-left]  (#1-right)  {};
    \node   [fit=(#1-left) (#1-right)]  (#1)        {};
                        }},
 %
every pin/.style={pin edge={<-, thick, gray!50}, align=left},
box/.style = {draw, inner sep=#1},
box/.default = 2mm,
 %
node distance = 4mm and 2mm,
  start chain = going left
                    ]
\foreach \x [count=\xx from 0] in {1,...,6}
{
\node (f\x) [on chain] {(*\,\x\,(factorial \xx))};
\node (n\x) [box,
             pin=left:E\x,
             above=of f\x]  {n\x};
\draw[->]   (n\x.north) -- ++ (0,4mm) coordinate (p\x);
}
%
\pic at ([shift={(-22mm,2mm)}] f6.north west) {two dots=PN}; % PN: petri net
\node (factorial) [above left=of PN.west |- p6] {factorial:};
\node[draw, inner sep=1mm, shift={(-1mm, 1mm)}, 
      pin=left:global\\ env,
      fit=(factorial) (p1)] {};
\draw[->] (factorial) -| (PN);
\draw[->] (PN-right.center) -| ([xshift=3mm] PN.east |- p6);
\draw[->] (PN-left.center) -- ++ (0,-1) 
            node[below, align=left] {parameters: n\\
                                     body: \dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very cool solution! If I ever have time to implement an actual library for drawing environment diagrams in TikZ, this will be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the two excellent solutions given above, there is another one which may be of use.

(I am only writing the part responsible for the actual positioning.)

```
\coordinate(g env south west) at (g env.south west);
\coordinate(g env south east) at (g env.south east);
\node (barycentric cs:g env south west=2,g env south east=8) {debug};
```

The values of the weights can be computed with `\mathexpr`.